# How can I configure spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, jms, azure-servicebus-queues

Found [this guide from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus) on how to listen to an Azure Service bus using JMS in Spring. I like the easy and clean implementation by using the `@JmsListener` annotation. I have got it to work, and would like to continue to use `@JmsListener(destination = "QUEUENAME", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")` and autoconfiguration. There are two problems with my current JMS approach; [by default no error handler is registered](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/f243a5396dbb03f2ddbc4f77c1fd6bb18e50a519/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAnnotationDrivenConfiguration.java#L83) and [transactions are not enabled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/jms/using.html#jms-mdp-simple), as I understand the docs.

I have read I can replace the default `jmsListenerContainerFactory` Bean with the following configuration code, which would solve the two problems.

```kotlin
@Bean
fun jmsListenerContainerFactory(
    connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory,
    errorHandler: CustomErrorHandler
): DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory {
    val factory = DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory()
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler)
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true)
    return factory
}
```

The new problem that now arises is `No qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory'`. Which is a problem probably related to the namespace changes in Spring Boot 3.

Is there a way to make `spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms` provide this ConnectionFactory as it previously did when everything was autoconfigured? Alternatively, is there an easy way to create a ConnectionFactory so I can connect to the service bus?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get this working, so ditched the library `spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms` in favor of `qpid-jms-client` (which I believe is the underlying library anyway). The following config works when I am using `qpid-jms-client`. (Client id is just needed for durable subscription, and it can be whatever)

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableJms
class AzureServiceBusConfiguration(
    @Value("\${spring.jms.servicebus.client-id}") private val clientId: String,
    private val log: Logger,
) {

    private fun connection(credentials: ServiceBusCredentials) =
        JmsConnectionFactory(credentials.username(), credentials.password(), credentials.remoteUri()).apply {
            clientID = clientId
        }

    private fun connectionFactory(connectionString: String) = CachingConnectionFactory(
        connection(ServiceBusCredentials(connectionString))
    )

    private fun listenerContainerFactory(connectionString: String) = DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory().apply {
        this.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory(connectionString))
        this.setSubscriptionDurable(true)
        this.setSessionTransacted(true)
        this.setErrorHandler { t -> log.error("Error in listener!", t) }
    }

    @Bean
    fun jmsListenerContainerFactory(
        @Value("\${spring.jms.servicebus.connection-string}")
        connectionString: String
    ) = listenerContainerFactory(connectionString)
}
```

The `JmsConnectionFactory` comes from `qpid-jms-client`